# strange exception (no such field embededHandle ) when create view rcp based on eclipse 32bit

Tags: eclipse, field, 32-bit

my product is a rcp based on eclipse and I embed some QT window to the eclipse view.  I successfully use PDE to build the rcp for 32bit and 64bit.

there is no error when I startup the 64bit rcp. all view is initialized correctly. but 
I met strange exception when I startup the 32bit rcp. it report exceptiob : no such field embededHandle.

the fact is the embededHandle is there defined in Compsite.class.

I don't know what to do right now. thanks in advance.

I just use reflection to print the fields of Composite, I find the modifier for embeddedHandle is different:
for 32bit , it is int.
for 64bit , it is long.

stack trace:

```
eclipse.buildId=M20110210-1200
java.version=1.6.0_29
java.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86, WS=gtk, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.rcp.product
Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.rcp.product -console -debug


java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: embeddedHandle
at com.x.x.x.views.GenericView.init(GenericView.java:80)
at com.x.x.x.views.GenericView.createPartControl(GenericView.java:101)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ViewReference.createPartHelper(ViewReference.java:375)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ViewReference.createPart(ViewReference.java:229)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPartReference.getPart(WorkbenchPartReference.java:595)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartPane.setVisible(PartPane.java:313)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ViewPane.setVisible(ViewPane.java:529)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.presentations.PresentablePart.setVisible(PresentablePart.java:180)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.presentations.util.PresentablePartFolder.select(PresentablePartFolder.java:270)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.presentations.util.LeftToRightTabOrder.select(LeftToRightTabOrder.java:65)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.presentations.util.TabbedStackPresentation.selectPart(TabbedStackPresentation.java:473)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartStack.refreshPresentationSelection(PartStack.java:1254)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartStack.setSelection(PartStack.java:1207)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartStack.showPart(PartStack.java:1606)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartStack.createControl(PartStack.java:647)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartStack.createControl(PartStack.java:574)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartSashContainer.createControl(PartSashContainer.java:568)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PerspectiveHelper.activate(PerspectiveHelper.java:272)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Perspective.onActivate(Perspective.java:981)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.setPerspective(WorkbenchPage.java:3614)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.busySetPerspective(WorkbenchPage.java:1041)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.access$16(WorkbenchPage.java:1025)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage$19.run(WorkbenchPage.java:3715)
at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.setPerspective(WorkbenchPage.java:3713)
at org.eclipse.ui.handlers.ShowPerspectiveHandler.openPerspective(ShowPerspectiveHandler.java:146)
at org.eclipse.ui.handlers.ShowPerspectiveHandler.openOther(ShowPerspectiveHandler.java:118)
at org.eclipse.ui.handlers.ShowPerspectiveHandler.execute(ShowPerspectiveHandler.java:57)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.HandlerProxy.execute(HandlerProxy.java:293)
at org.eclipse.core.commands.Command.executeWithChecks(Command.java:476)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.HandlerService.executeCommand(HandlerService.java:178)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.SlaveHandlerService.executeCommand(SlaveHandlerService.java:247)
at org.eclipse.ui.actions.PerspectiveMenu.runOther(PerspectiveMenu.java:376)
at org.eclipse.ui.actions.PerspectiveMenu$3.runWithEvent(PerspectiveMenu.java:130)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:584)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.access$2(ActionContributionItem.java:501)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem$5.handleEvent(ActionContributionItem.java:411)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1258)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:3540)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3161)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2640)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2604)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2438)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:671)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:664)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:115)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:369)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:620)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:575)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1408)
```

Comment: Could you post the stack trace?

Answer (score 1):

We had a similar issue with compile time (int) vs. runtime (long) with the similar field Control.handle, subclassing Control. Depending on the fragment (x86 or x86_64), the field is either "int" or "long".

Instead of

```
this.handle
```

we moved to:

```
Control.class.getField("handle").getLong(this)
```